# VB.net Need Text Box to Only Accept Numbers

Tags: vb.net, textbox, numbers

I'm fairly new to VB.net (self taught) and was just wondering if someone out there could help me out with some code. I'm not trying to do anything too involved, just have a `TextBox` that accepts a numeric value from 1 to 10. I don't want it to accept a string or any number above 10. If someone types a word or character an error message will appear, telling him to enter a valid number. This is what I have; obviously it's not great as I am having problems. Thanks again to anyone who can help.

```
 If TxtBox.Text > 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Number from 1 to 10")
        TxtBox.Focus()
    ElseIf TxtBox.Text < 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Thank You, your rating was " & TxtBox.Text)
        Total = Total + 1
    ElseIf IsNumeric(TxtBox.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you, your rating was " & ValueTxtBox.Text)
    End If

    ValueTxtBox.Clear()
    ValueTxtBox.Focus()
```

Answer (score 44):

You can do this with the use of Ascii integers. Put this code in the Textbox's Keypress event. `e.KeyChar` represents the key that's pressed. And the the built-in function `Asc()` converts it into its Ascii integer.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    '97 - 122 = Ascii codes for simple letters
    '65 - 90  = Ascii codes for capital letters
    '48 - 57  = Ascii codes for numbers

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I found the code to be most useful, but wanted to give you guys a heads up that this code will not prevent someone from pasting in any of the non-desired characters as the keypress event does not occur during the paste and multiple characters can be pasted in too during the paste. I would suggest an additional line of checking the resultant string being entered for conformance to what is acceptable as an end result.

Comment: I give you an upvote for thinking of copy/paste, but I found this acutally has the opposite problem. You can't copy/paste letters, but you also can't copy/paste numbers.

Comment: @DavidSchmidt Thank you, I read your comment now after trying the above code, YOU ARE SO RIGHT.

Answer (score 25):

This is what I did in order to handle both key entry and copy/paste.

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox.KeyPress
    If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox.TextChanged
    Dim digitsOnly As Regex = New Regex("[^\d]")
    TextBox.Text = digitsOnly.Replace(TextBox.Text, "")
End Sub
```

If you want to allow decimals and negative amount, add

```vb
AndAlso Not e.KeyChar = "." AndAlso Not e.keyChar = "-"
```

to the if statement in the KeyPress section.

Answer (score 11):

## Simplest ever solution for ***TextBox Validation in VB.NET***

[image: TextBox Validation for Visual Basic (VB.NET)]

First, add new VB code file in your project.

1. Go To **Solution Explorer**
2. **Right Click** to your project
3. Select **Add** > **New item...**
4. Add new VB code file (i.e. example.vb)

**or** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

COPY & PASTE following code into this file and give it a suitable name. (i.e. KeyValidation.vb)

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
    Public Enum ValidationType
        Only_Numbers = 1
        Only_Characters = 2
        Not_Null = 3
        Only_Email = 4
        Phone_Number = 5
    End Enum
    Public Sub AssignValidation(ByRef CTRL As Windows.Forms.TextBox, ByVal Validation_Type As ValidationType)
        Dim txt As Windows.Forms.TextBox = CTRL
        Select Case Validation_Type
            Case ValidationType.Only_Numbers
                AddHandler txt.KeyPress, AddressOf number_Leave
            Case ValidationType.Only_Characters
                AddHandler txt.KeyPress, AddressOf OCHAR_Leave
            Case ValidationType.Not_Null
                AddHandler txt.Leave, AddressOf NotNull_Leave
            Case ValidationType.Only_Email
                AddHandler txt.Leave, AddressOf Email_Leave
            Case ValidationType.Phone_Number
                AddHandler txt.KeyPress, AddressOf Phonenumber_Leave
        End Select
    End Sub
    Public Sub number_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
        Dim numbers As Windows.Forms.TextBox = sender
        If InStr("1234567890.", e.KeyChar) = 0 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Or (e.KeyChar = "." And InStr(numbers.Text, ".") > 0) Then
            e.KeyChar = Chr(0)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub Phonenumber_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
        Dim numbers As Windows.Forms.TextBox = sender
        If InStr("1234567890.()-+ ", e.KeyChar) = 0 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Or (e.KeyChar = "." And InStr(numbers.Text, ".") > 0) Then
            e.KeyChar = Chr(0)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub OCHAR_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
        If InStr("1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+=-", e.KeyChar) > 0 Then
            e.KeyChar = Chr(0)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub NotNull_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim No As Windows.Forms.TextBox = sender
        If No.Text.Trim = "" Then
            MsgBox("This field Must be filled!")
            No.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub Email_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim Email As Windows.Forms.TextBox = sender
        If Email.Text <> "" Then
            Dim rex As Match = Regex.Match(Trim(Email.Text), "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
            If rex.Success = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a valid Email Address", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                Email.BackColor = Color.Red
                Email.Focus()
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Email.BackColor = Color.White
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Now use following code to Form Load Event like below.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AssignValidation(Me.TextBox1, ValidationType.Only_Digits)
        AssignValidation(Me.TextBox2, ValidationType.Only_Characters)
        AssignValidation(Me.TextBox3, ValidationType.No_Blank)
        AssignValidation(Me.TextBox4, ValidationType.Only_Email)
End Sub
```

Done..!

Comment: I've used this method a couple times now in different projects and it's always worked perfectly for my needs.  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I add a MODULE, and use only_numbers, no only_digist. GREAT job!!

Comment: Worked flawlessly for me on `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64 bits) - Versión 17.4.4`
Only detail is you need to change `Only_Digits` to `Only_Numbers` on the Form Load Private Sub.

Answer (score 9):

You must first validate if the input is actually an integer. You can do it with `Integer.TryParse`:

```
Dim intValue As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(TxtBox.Text, intValue) AndAlso intValue > 0 AndAlso intValue < 11 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Thank You, your rating was " & TxtBox.Text)
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Number from 1 to 10")
End If
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer which most closely matches the question without doing a complex key handling.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Private Sub txtCaseID_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtCaseID.KeyPress
    If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then e.KeyChar = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid any code by using a NumericUpDown control rather than a text box, this automatically only allows numbers and has a max and min.
It also allow accessing the number directly with `NumericUpDown1.Value` as well as using up and down arrows to set the number.
Also if a number higher/over the max is entered it will jump to the nearest allowed number.

Comment: True, although NumericUpDown is usually best for entering smaller numbers.  I would think it odd to have those up/down arrows on an input field where I am expected to enter a number in thousands or millions, like dollar amounts.  Less importantly, NumericUpDown have annoying UI problems related to the font size.

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyTextBox.KeyPress
    If Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub textBox5_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles textBox5.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Data_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Data.KeyPress
    If (Not e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Back) And ("0123456789.").IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1) Or (e.KeyChar = "." And Data.Text.ToCharArray().Count(Function(c) c = ".") > 0) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim ch(10) As Char
Dim len As Integer
len = TextBox1.Text.Length
ch = TextBox1.Text.ToCharArray()
For i = 0 To len - 1
    If Not IsNumeric(ch(i)) Then
        MsgBox("Value you insert is not numeric")
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not e.KeyChar = "." AndAlso Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.KeyChar = ""
End If
```

This allow you to use delete key and set decimal points

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but I wanted to share something I have implemented to turn a TextBox into what I call an IntBox.

First you need to make an extension with:

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function HandledStringtoInteger(s As String) As Integer
    Try
        If s = String.Empty Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return Integer.Parse(s)
        End If
    Catch
        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        Dim ReturnInt As Integer
        Dim Parsed As Integer
        For Each Character In s.ToCharArray
            If Character = "-" Then
                If s.Substring(0, 1).ToString <> "-" Then
                    result = Character + result
                End If
            End If
            If Character = "." Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If Integer.TryParse(Character, Parsed) Then
                result = result + Parsed.ToString
            End If
        Next
        If result <> String.Empty Then
            If Integer.TryParse(result, ReturnInt) Then
                Return Integer.Parse(ReturnInt)
            Else
                If Double.Parse(result) > Double.Parse(Integer.MaxValue.ToString) Then
                    Return Integer.MaxValue
                ElseIf Double.Parse(result) < Double.Parse(Integer.MinValue.ToString) Then
                    Return Integer.MinValue
                Else
                    Return Integer.Parse(ReturnInt)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

Then make a TextChanged event sub:

```
Private Sub TextBox_to_IntBox(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles YourTextBox.TextChanged
    If DirectCast(sender, TextBox).IsKeyboardFocused Then
        DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text = DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text.HandledStringtoInteger
        DirectCast(sender, TextBox).CaretIndex = DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text.Length
    End If
End Sub
```

Then whenever the user enters text it evaluates the string and only returns numeric values that are within the bounds of a standard Integer. With the "-" character you can change the integer from positive to negative and back again.

If anyone sees anything that can improve this code let me know but my tests show this works fantastic to make an IntBox.

EDIT:
I found another method that can work if you use properties in your code. (Note this will need a separate property per TextBox)

First create the property:

```
Public Class Properties
    Implement INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _Variable as Integer
    Public Property YourProperty as Object
    get
      Return _Variable
    end get
    set(value as Object)
      _Variable = value.ToString.ToInteger 'I will give the ToInteger extension code later
    end set
    end property
Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Public Sub OnPropertyChange(ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
    If Not PropertyChangedEvent Is Nothing Then
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, e)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Then make the binding in your window's main class:

```
Public WithEvents _YourVariable as New Properties

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
With YourTextBox
  .SetBinding(Textbox.TextProperty, New Binding("YourProperty"))
  .DataContext = _YourVariable
End With
End Sub
```

Finally here is the ToInteger Extension Code I set up:

```
''' <summary>
''' Handles conversion of variable to Integer.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="X"></param>
''' <param name="I">Returned if conversion fails.</param>
''' <returns>Signed 32bit Integer</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function toInteger(Of T)(ByRef X As T, Optional I As Integer = 0) As Integer
    Dim S As String = X.ToString
    Try
        If S = String.Empty Then
            Return I
        Else
            Return Integer.Parse(S)
        End If
    Catch
        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        Dim ReturnInt As Integer
        Dim Parsed As Byte
        For Each Character In S.ToCharArray
            If Character = "-" Then
                If S.Substring(0, 1).ToString <> "-" Then
                    result = Character + result
                End If
            End If
            If Character = "." Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If Byte.TryParse(Character, Parsed) Then
                result = result + Parsed.ToString
            End If
        Next
        If result <> String.Empty Then
            If Integer.TryParse(result, ReturnInt) Then
                Return Integer.Parse(ReturnInt)
            Else
                If Double.Parse(result) > Double.Parse(Integer.MaxValue.ToString) Then
                    Return Integer.MaxValue
                ElseIf Double.Parse(result) < Double.Parse(Integer.MinValue.ToString) Then
                    Return Integer.MinValue
                Else
                    Return Integer.Parse(ReturnInt)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Return I
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

With all these combined whenever they type something into the box it will act as if it were a textbox but when they change focus the ToInteger extension will set the value as an integer into the property and return it to the textbox.

Meaning that if the operator entered "-1w3" after focus changes it will return as "-13" automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This may be too late, but for other new blood on VB out there, here's something simple.

First, in any case, unless your application would require, blocking user's key entry is somehow not a good thing to do, users may misinterpret the action as problem on the hardware keyboard and at the same time may not see where their keypreesed entry error came from.

Here's a simple one, let user's freely type their entry then trap the error later:

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim theNumber As Integer
        Dim theEntry As String = Trim(TextBox1.Text)

        'This check if entry can be converted to
        'numeric value from 0-10, if cannot return a negative value.
        Try
            theNumber = Convert.ToInt32(theEntry)
            If theNumber < 0 Or theNumber > 10 Then theNumber = -1
        Catch ex As Exception
            theNumber = -1
        End Try

        'Trap for the valid and invalid numeric number
        If theNumber < 0 Or theNumber > 10 Then
            MsgBox("Invalid Entry, allows (0-10) only.")
            'entry was invalid return cursor to entry box.
            TextBox1.Focus()
        Else
            'Entry accepted:
            ' Continue process your thing here...

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. If your user cannot tell why he can only enter numbers in your TextBox, your application likely has a bigger UI problem.  Good web apps perform validation as users type or leave input fields.  Do the same in .NET apps.  Moreover, in your case, you would probably prefer to handle the Validating event.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the solution where it will check whether the text is range 1 to 10 : [1-9] will check for the range from 1 to 9. I use one more condition to check for 10.

```
If txtBox.Text Like "[1-9]" Or txtBox.Text Like "10" Then
        MessageBox.Show("true")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("false")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all set the TextBox's `MaxLength` to 2 that will limit the amount of text entry in your `TextBox`. Then you can try something like this using the [`KeyPress Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx). Since you are using a 2 digit maximum (10) you will need to use a `Key` such as `Enter` to initiate the check.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    If Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then    'Check if Numeric
        If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then  'If not Numeric Check if a Control
            If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
                If Val(tb.Text) > 10 Then  'Check Bounds
                    tb.Text = ""
                    ShowPassFail(False)
                Else
                    ShowPassFail(True)
                End If
                e.Handled = True
            End If
            Exit Sub
        End If
        e.Handled = True
        ShowPassFail(False)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ShowPassFail(pass As Boolean)
    If pass Then
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you, your rating was " & TextBox1.Text)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Number from 1 to 10")
    End If
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Follow code Textbox Keypress Event:

```vb
Private Sub txtbox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtbox1.KeyPress
    Try
        If Val(txtbox1.text) < 10 Then
            If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        Else
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ShowException(ex.Message, MESSAGEBOX_TITLE, ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This code allow numbers only and you can enter only number between 1 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function Isnumber(ByVal KCode As String) As Boolean
    If Not Isnumeric(KCode) And KCode <> ChrW(Keys.Back) And KCode <> ChrW(Keys.Enter) And KCode <> "."c Then

        MsgBox("Please Enter Numbers only", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    End If
End Function

Private Sub txtBalance_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtBalance.KeyPress

    If Not Isnumber(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.KeyChar = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **onkeydown** Property of the TextBox for limiting its value to numbers only.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeydown = "return (!(event.keyCode>=65) && event.keyCode!=32);"></asp:TextBox>
```

**!(keyCode>=65)** check is for excludng Alphabets.

**keyCode!=32** check is for excluding Space character inbetween the numbers.

If you want to exclude Symbols also from entering into the textbox, then include the below condition also in the 'onkeydown' property.

```
!(event.shiftKey && (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57))
```

Thus the TextBox will finally become

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeydown = "return (!(event.keyCode>=65) && event.keyCode!=32 && !(event.shiftKey && (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)));"></asp:TextBox>
```

***Explanation:***

KeyCode for 'a' is '65' and 'z' is '90'.

KeyCodes from '90' to '222' which are other symbols are also not needed.

KeyCode for 'Space' Key is '32' which is also not needed.

Then a combination of 'Shift' key and 'Number' keys (which denotes Symbols) also not needed. KeyCode for '0' is '48' and '9' is '57'.

Hence all these are included in the TextBox declaration itself which produces the desired result.

Try and see.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... just clear the textbox completely as non-numeric keys are pressed.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) Then
        'nada
    Else
        TextBox2.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this function in any module inside your vb.net project.

```
Public Function MakeTextBoxNumeric(kcode As Integer, shift As Boolean) As Boolean
    If kcode >= 96 And kcode <= 105 Then

    ElseIf kcode >= 48 And kcode <= 57
        If shift = True Then Return False
    ElseIf kcode = 8 Or kcode = 107 Then

    ElseIf kcode = 187 Then
        If shift = False Then Return False
    Else
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Then use this function inside your textbox_keydown event like below:

```
Private Sub txtboxNumeric_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtboxNumeric.KeyDown
If MakeTextBoxNumeric(e.KeyCode, e.Shift) = False Then e.SuppressKeyPress = True
End Sub
```

And yes. It works 100% :)

Answer (score 0):

This was my final... It gets around all the type issues also:

Here is a simple textbox that requires a number:

```
   public Sub textbox_memorytotal_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textbox_memorytotal.TextChanged
        TextboxOnlyNumbers(sender)
    End Sub
```

and here is the procedure that corrects all bad input:

```
Public Sub TextboxOnlyNumbers(ByRef objTxtBox As TextBox)

    ' ONLY allow numbers
    If Not IsNumeric(objTxtBox.Text) Then

        ' Don't process things like too many backspaces
        If objTxtBox.Text.Length > 0 Then

            MsgBox("Numerical Values only!")

            Try
                ' If something bad was entered delete the last character
                objTxtBox.Text = objTxtBox.Text.Substring(0, objTxtBox.Text.Length - 1)

                ' Put the cursor and the END of the corrected number
                objTxtBox.Select(objTxtBox.Text.Length + 1, 1)

            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your Textbox Keydown event.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    'you can enter decimal "if nonNumberEntered(e, TextBox1, True) then" 
    'otherwise just numbers "if nonNumberEntered(e, TextBox1) then"
    If nonNumberEntered(e, TextBox1, True) Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        'put your code here
    End If

End Sub
```

Copy this function in any module inside your vb.net project.

```
Public Function nonNumberEntered(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs, _
                          ByVal ob As TextBox, _
                          Optional ByVal decim As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    nonNumberEntered = False

    If decim Then
        ' Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the top of the keyboard.
        If e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 OrElse e.KeyCode > Keys.D9 Then
            ' Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the keypad.
            If e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 OrElse e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9 Then
                If e.KeyCode <> Keys.Decimal And e.KeyCode <> Keys.OemPeriod Then
                    If e.KeyCode <> Keys.Divide And e.KeyCode <> Keys.OemQuestion Then
                        ' Determine whether the keystroke is a backspace.
                        If e.KeyCode <> Keys.Back And e.KeyCode <> Keys.Delete _
                        And e.KeyCode <> Keys.Left And e.KeyCode <> Keys.Right Then
                            ' A non-numerical keystroke was pressed. 
                            nonNumberEntered = True
                        End If
                    ElseIf ob.Text.Contains("/") Or ob.Text.Length = 0 Then
                        nonNumberEntered = True
                    End If
                ElseIf ob.Text.Contains(".") Or ob.Text.Length = 0 Then
                    nonNumberEntered = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
        ' Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the top of the keyboard.
        If e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 OrElse e.KeyCode > Keys.D9 Then
            ' Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the keypad.
            If e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 OrElse e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9 Then
                ' Determine whether the keystroke is a backspace.
                If e.KeyCode <> Keys.Back And e.KeyCode <> Keys.Delete _
                    And e.KeyCode <> Keys.Left And e.KeyCode <> Keys.Right Then
                    ' A non-numerical keystroke was pressed. 
                    nonNumberEntered = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'If shift key was pressed, it's not a number.
    If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Shift Then
        nonNumberEntered = True
    End If

End Function
```

This will allow numbers like 2/4 or numbers like 3.5 to be entered in your textbox if using decim "nonNumberEntered(e,Textbox1, True)".

Allows only numbers to be entered in textbox if using "nonNumberEntered(e,Textbox1, False)" or "nonNumberEntered(e,Textbox1)".

> Edit: added text.

Comment: you need to add text to the answer. What does the code do?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use requirement recently for a `TextBox` which could only take numbers.

In the end I used a `MaskedTextBox` instead of a `TextBox`. You define a "mask" for the textbox and it will only accept characters which you have defined - in this case, numbers. The downside is that it leaves a bit of an ugly line within the `TextBox`;

[image: A text mask]

What I loved about the `MaskedTextBox` was it was so customisable. If, for whatever reason you wanted a `TextBox` to only accept an input in the format of 3 ints followed by 2 letters, all you need to do is set the `TextMask` to `000LL`. There are a load of pre-defined masks within Visual Studio, and the full documentation can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx).

[image: Pre-defined masks]

Now, I know this doesn't fully solve your issue, but the use of a `MaskedTextBox` takes away a huge part of the complexity of the problem. You can now guarantee that the contents of the `MaskedTextBox` will only ever be an `Int`, allowing you to run a simple `If` statement to ensure the value is `=<10`

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I want to share my code.

```
 Private Sub txtbox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtbox1.TextChanged
    If txtbox1.Text.Length > 0 Then
        If Not IsNumeric(txtbox1.Text) Then
            Dim sel As Integer = txtbox1.SelectionStart
            txtbox1.Text = txtbox1.Text.Remove(sel - 1, 1)
            txtbox1.SelectionStart = sel - 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

On each entry in textbox (event - Handles RestrictedTextBox.TextChanged), you can do a try to caste entered text into integer, if failure occurs, you just reset the value of the text in RestrictedTextBox to last valid entry (which gets constantly updating under the temp1 variable).

Here's how to go about it. In the sub that loads with the form (me.load or mybase.load), initialize temp1 to the default value of RestrictedTextBox.Text

```
Dim temp1 As Integer 'initialize temp1 default value, you should do this after the default value for RestrictedTextBox.Text was loaded.
If (RestrictedTextBox.Text = Nothing) Then 
    temp1 = Nothing
Else
    Try 
        temp1 = CInt(RestrictedTextBox.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        temp1 = Nothing
    End Try
End If
```

At any other point in form:

```
Private Sub textBox_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RestrictedTextBox.TextChanged
    Try
        temp1 = CInt(RestrictedTextBox.Text) 'If user inputs integer, this will succeed and temp will be updated
    Catch ex As Exception
        RestrictedTextBox.Text = temp1.ToString 'If user inputs non integer, textbox will be reverted to state the state it was in before the string entry
    End Try
End Sub
```

The nice thing about this is that you can use this to restrict a textbox to any type you want: double, uint etc....

Answer (score 0):

every text box has a **validating** and **validated** event you can use then as follows :-

```
Private Sub PriceTxt_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles PriceTxt.Validating
                If Not IsNumeric(PriceTxt.Text) Then
                 PriceTxt.BackColor = Color.Red
                 MsgBox("The Price Should Be Numeric Only , Enter Again", vbCritical)
                 PriceTxt.Text = ""
                 PriceTxt.BackColor = Color.White
                End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old.. I'll just leave this code here for the sake of convenience.

Integer only:

```
Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
   With TextBox1
      If IsNumeric(.Text) Then .Text = .Text.Select(Function(x) If(IsNumeric(x), x, "")) : .SelectionStart = .TextLength
   End With
   ' etc..
End Sub
```

Accepts `Double`:

```
Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
   With TextBox1
      If IsNumeric(.Text) Then .Text = .Text.Select(Function(x) If(IsNumeric(x) Or x = ".", x, "")) : .SelectionStart = .TextLength
   End With
   ' etc..
End Sub
```

Accepts basic operations `+ - * /`, parentheses `( ) [ ] { }` and `Double`:

```
Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
   With TextBox1
      If IsNumeric(.Text) Then .Text = .Text.Select(Function(x) If(IsNumeric(x) Or ".+-*/()[]{}".Contains(x), x, "")) : .SelectionStart = .TextLength
   End With
   ' etc..
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple piece of code that works for me.

```
 Private Sub Textbox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles textbox1.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) > 58 Then
            e.KeyChar = ""

        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me.  It allows backspace, del, as well as numbers from the top row of the keyboard and the number pad.  It excludes the + and - signs.

```
    Private Sub tbMQTTPort_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles tbMQTTPort.KeyDown

      Dim kc As New KeyConverter
      Dim Regex = New Regex("[^0-9]+")
      e.Handled = Regex.IsMatch(kc.ConvertToInvariantString(e.Key).Replace("NumPad", ""))

    End Sub
```