# How to let my program understand all math marks such as "+" , "*" that has written in textbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make Calculator.My Program Calculator is Running and can make Calculations but I have a problem, I want a code that let my program understand all math marks such as "+" , "*" that has written in textbox.

**What I nead?**
I need a code that let my program understand what i write in textbox for example:
I Write this Calculation in textbox

(1+5)*(1-3)/2

**I hope you understand what I want**

Comment: You said you have a problem. Is the problem _I want a code_?

Comment: Maybe this is an alternative approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969824/vb-net-need-text-box-to-only-accept-numbers

Comment: i know how to enter number only ..RhinoDevel .., I need how to let my program to understand what excatly Write in textbox like (fx-500) I Write the problem and press Equal , I find Results.

Comment: thanks a lot ..Raymond Chen.. it is exactly what I need