# How to restrict user only being able to enter integer in textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, integer, restriction

When user wants to calculate their BMI, how do I restrict them so they can only enter integer in the textbox when the program loads?

Also if possible how can I turn the BMI answer into 2 or 1 decimal place?

**CODE:**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

        txtHeight.Text = txtHeight.Text / 100 ' converts txtheight into meter

        lblBMI.Text = txtWeight.Text / txtHeight.Text ^ 2 'BMI is equal to txtweight divided by (txtheight)^2

        'BMI = x KG / (y M * y M)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Thats the Design

[image]

I know its probably very simple but I'm fairly new to programming, Thank you!

Comment: Images are not the way you post code here, please edit your question and post the code.

Comment: Ok sure, sorry I thought image with the code would be enough :)

Comment: Use a NumericUpDown control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969824/vb-net-need-text-box-to-only-accept-numbers)

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    '97 - 122 = Ascii codes for simple letters
    '65 - 90  = Ascii codes for capital letters
    '48 - 57  = Ascii codes for numbers

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Formatting number into Decimal places:

```
YourLabel.Text = FormatNumber(YourNumber,N) 'N = Number of Decimal Places
```

Comment: Its coming up with blue underline wherever "e.KeyChar" and "e.handled" is. It says "Not a memeber of 'System.EventArgs'.

Comment: In which event did you put it?

Comment: Add the code in the _KeyPress_ event of your textbox.

Comment: oh I put it in "TextChanged" event. Haha then I realized you had to put it in  "Keypress" event. Thank you, it works! :D