# Numeric Validation

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So I have a program that keeps track of the score after each baseball inning and adds up the score from each consecutive inning in a ListBox.
The only part which I am having trouble with is user validation, to make sure that the input is numeric and cannot pass non-numeric values.
What is the easiest way to accomplish this? A ListBox and a Inputbox is required.

The code is below:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim intRunningTotal As Integer = 0
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()

        For inning = 1 To 7 Step 1
            Dim strScore As String = InputBox("Enter the score of inning " + inning.ToString(), "Score")
            Dim intScore As Integer = strScore
            intRunningTotal = intRunningTotal + intScore
            ListBox1.Items.Add(inning.ToString() + vbTab + intScore.ToString() + vbTab + intRunningTotal.ToString())
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.net Need Text Box to Only Accept Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969824/vb-net-need-text-box-to-only-accept-numbers)

Comment: You could provide a single interface with some NumericUpDown controls as the input for the scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a For Loop and InputBox, add a TextBox to your Form and use that as the input mechanism.  Just like in the example from Sebastian, use [Integer.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) to parse the TextBox to an Integer each time the Button is pressed (only one number per button click).  Once you have seven things in your ListBox, you can disable the Button and the TextBox so that no more inputs can be made (or you can make the Button click tell the user they already have seven inputs):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Static intRunningTotal As Integer = 0
    Dim intScore As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, intScore) Then
        If intScore >= 0 Then
            intRunningTotal = intRunningTotal + intScore
            Dim entry As String = (ListBox1.Items.Count + 1).ToString() + vbTab + intScore.ToString() + vbTab + intRunningTotal.ToString()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(entry)
            If ListBox1.Items.Count = 7 Then
                Button1.Enabled = False
                TextBox1.Enabled = False
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Score must be greater than or equal to zero.")
            TextBox1.Focus()
            TextBox1.SelectAll()
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Score.  Please try again.")
        TextBox1.Focus()
        TextBox1.SelectAll()
    End If
End Sub
```

> Sorry, but I forgot to mention in the original post that I am
>   restricted to using an InputBox (pop up dialog box) and cannot use a
>   textbox (embedded in the UI). The button must trigger an input box to
>   pop up. The score must be in a listbox. Anything else is allowed

Here's another version, then:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim valid As Boolean
    Dim intRunningTotal As Integer = 0
    For inning As Integer = 1 To 7
        Do
            valid = False
            Dim strResponse As String = InputBox("Enter the score of inning " + inning.ToString() & ": ", "Score")
            Dim intScore As Integer
            If Integer.TryParse(strResponse, intScore) Then
                If intScore >= 0 Then
                    valid = True
                    intRunningTotal = intRunningTotal + intScore
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(inning.ToString() + vbTab + intScore.ToString() + vbTab + intRunningTotal.ToString())
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Score must be greater than or equal to zero.")
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Score.  Please try again.")
            End If
        Loop While Not valid
    Next
End Sub
```

> The same issue is occurring from the other users code in the code
>   provided where you cannot break out of the input box on command if
>   cancel or the x is clicked, it will show up as invalid score instead
>   of breaking out.

You didn't list that as a requirement.  **There is no difference between an empty input and clicking "OK", versus when the "X" or Cancel has been clicked.**  You can check for a blank string being returned, and drop out like this:

```
Dim strResponse As String = InputBox("Enter the score of inning " + inning.ToString() & ": ", "Score")
If strResponse = "" Then
    Exit For ' ...or Exit Sub
End If
```

This is a well known limitation of InputBox, and one the reasons it is rarely used...

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot to mention in the original post that I am restricted to using an InputBox (pop up dialog box) and cannot use a textbox (embedded in the UI). The button must trigger an input box to pop up. The score must be in a listbox. Anything else is allowed.

Comment: The same issue is occurring from the other users code in the code provided where you cannot break out of the input box on command if cancel or the x is clicked, it will show up as invalid score instead of breaking out.

Answer (score 0):

Integer.TryParse(string, integerVariable) will check the string to see if it can be converted to an Integer. It will return True or False so it can be used in an If statemnent. In addition it fills the integerVariable with the Integer representation of the string.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim intRunningTotal As Integer = 0
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()
    Dim inning As Integer = 1
    'changed to a do loop so I could increment inning in the If statement
    'It will only increment if the parse is succesful
    Do
        Dim strScore As String = InputBox("Enter the score of inning " + inning.ToString(), "Score")
        Dim intScore As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(strScore, intScore) Then
            'This is a shortcut way to write intRunningTotal = intRunningTotal + intScore
            intRunningTotal += intScore
            ListBox2.Items.Add(inning.ToString() + vbTab + intScore.ToString() + vbTab + intRunningTotal.ToString())
            inning += 1
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
        End If
    Loop While inning < 8
End Sub
```