# Is it possible to convert vba code that can be used in vbnet?

Tags: vba, vb.net, time

Good day,

I have this code that I used from vba excel

```
Private Sub txtSTime_Change()

Dim ascii   As Integer
Dim h       As Integer
Dim m       As Integer
Dim n       As Integer

    n = Len(txtSTime.Value)
    
    If n = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
        ascii = Asc(Right(txtSTime.Value, 1))
        ' Validate the hour is 2 digits from 01 to 23.
        If n = 2 And ascii <> 58 And CharCode <> 8 Then
            h = CInt(Left(txtSTime.Value, 2))
            If h < 0 Or h > 23 Then
                MsgBox "Invalid hour " & h & vbLf & "Hours are from 00 to 23."
                txtSTime.Value = ""
                Me.txtSTime.SetFocus
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        
        ' Validate the month is 2 digits from 01 to 12.
        If n = 5 And ascii <> 58 And CharCode <> 8 Then
            m = CInt(Mid(txtSTime.Value, 4, 2))
            If m < 0 Or m > 59 Then
                MsgBox "Invalid minute " & m & vbLf & "Minutes are from 00 to 59."
                txtSTime.Value = Left(txtSTime.Value, 3)
                Me.txtSTime.SetFocus
                txtSTime.Value = ""
            End If
        End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtSTime_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    CharCode = 0
    n = KeyCode
    
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 8, 10, 13, 46: CharCode = KeyCode  ' Process these control characters: BS, LF, CR and Delete.
        Case 48 To 57, 96 To 105                ' Display numbers and forward slahes from keyboard and number pad.
        Case 186 And Shift = 1                  ' Display the colon.
        Case Else: KeyCode = 0                  ' Erase all other input.
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub txtSTime_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

Dim char    As String
Dim n       As Integer

    n = Len(txtSTime)
    
    If n > 0 Then char = Right(txtSTime, 1)
    
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 48 To 57, 96 To 105
            ' Automatically add the colon after the day and month.
            If n = 3 Then
                txtSTime.Value = Left(txtSTime.Value, n - 1) & ":" & char
            End If
        Case 183 And Shift = 1
            ' Display the colon only after the minutes.
            If n <> 3 Then
                txtSTime.Value = Left(txtSTime.Value, n - 1)
            End If
    End Select

End Sub
```

Its function is that whenever I type number on my txtSTime textbox it automatically change the number into an 24Hour time format.
Example I typed "1220" it automatically change into "12:20"

I tried looking for the same function in vb.net but I can't seem to find anything.

It is possible to convert the code from vba excel that can be used in vb.net?

Comment: Instead of trying to find something, how about you try to write something? Read the VBA code and understand what it actually does. If there's something you don't specifically understand then ask about that, either here or elsewhere. Once you do understand, work out how to implement the same functionality in VB.NET. If what you try doesn't work, ask about that specifically. This site is about specific programming problems, not getting others to write your code for you.

Comment: For the record, the best code to do the same thing in VB.NET would be waaaaaaaayyyyy shorter, i.e. two lines.

Comment: In VB.NET you can just use a date control instead of a textbox, and set it into time only format (custom if you want to) - no need for code that validates the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was from VBA as well and now I'm practicing VB.net and C#
It does not have to be that complicated now days. As for your solution, there are 2 things you need to take care. First make the user is entering numeric. You may refer to
[VB.net Need Text Box to Only Accept Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969824/vb-net-need-text-box-to-only-accept-numbers)

Secondly, you can use a split function to format your text

```
Dim txt As String = txtSTime.Text
Dim Result As String = txt.Substring(0, 2) & ":" & txt.Substring(3, 2)
txtSTime.Text = Result
```